# Android rss fedd

Tags: android, http, rss

I have a problem with my android application when i try to connect to read the rss feed, some times it works and sometimes it works only with the emulator and do not work with devices !!

```
package com.itgrapes.rss;


public class ContainerData {    

static public Context context;

public ContainerData() {

}


public static ArrayList<Feed> getFeeds(String urlPage){
    URL url=null;
    SAXParserFactory fabrique = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser parseur = null;
    ArrayList<Feed> feeds = null;
    try {
        parseur = fabrique.newSAXParser();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        url = new URL(urlPage);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    DefaultHandler handler = new ParserXMLHandler();
    try {
        parseur.parse(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), handler);
        feeds = ((ParserXMLHandler) handler).getData();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.i("SAXException", "SAXException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("IOException", "IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return feeds;
}

}
```

This is the log.

```
        10-06 14:01:57.991: D/dalvikvm(414): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 70K, 52% free 2612K/5379K, external 1896K/2137K, paused 105ms
        10-06 14:02:08.772: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.onHoverEvent, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.onHoverEvent
        10-06 14:02:08.772: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4164: Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
        10-06 14:02:08.781: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
        10-06 14:02:08.781: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0004 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
        10-06 14:02:08.812: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.getAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.getAlpha
        10-06 14:02:08.812: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2935: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.getAlpha ()F
        10-06 14:02:08.812: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
        10-06 14:02:08.826: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.getAlpha ()F
        10-06 14:02:08.826: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.getTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.getTranslationY
        10-06 14:02:08.832: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2936: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.getTranslationY ()F
        10-06 14:02:08.832: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
        10-06 14:02:08.832: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.getTranslationY ()F
        10-06 14:02:08.832: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.setAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.setAlpha
        10-06 14:02:08.832: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2939: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
        10-06 14:02:08.832: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
        10-06 14:02:08.832: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
        10-06 14:02:08.832: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.setTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.setTranslationY
        10-06 14:02:08.843: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2947: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.setTranslationY (F)V
        10-06 14:02:08.843: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
        10-06 14:02:08.843: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.setTranslationY (F)V
        10-06 14:02:08.882: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.getAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.getAlpha
        10-06 14:02:08.882: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2717: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getAlpha ()F
        10-06 14:02:08.891: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
        10-06 14:02:08.891: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getAlpha ()F
        10-06 14:02:08.903: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.getTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.getTranslationX
        10-06 14:02:08.903: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2723: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getTranslationX ()F
        10-06 14:02:08.903: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
        10-06 14:02:08.903: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getTranslationX ()F
        10-06 14:02:08.922: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.getTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.getTranslationY
        10-06 14:02:08.922: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2724: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getTranslationY ()F
        10-06 14:02:08.922: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
        10-06 14:02:08.943: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getTranslationY ()F
        10-06 14:02:08.943: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.setAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.setAlpha
        10-06 14:02:08.943: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2739: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setAlpha (F)V
        10-06 14:02:08.952: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
        10-06 14:02:08.952: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setAlpha (F)V
        10-06 14:02:08.962: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.setTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.setTranslationX
        10-06 14:02:08.962: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2743: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setTranslationX (F)V
        10-06 14:02:08.962: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
        10-06 14:02:08.962: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setTranslationX (F)V
        10-06 14:02:08.962: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.setTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.setTranslationY
        10-06 14:02:08.962: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2744: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setTranslationY (F)V
        10-06 14:02:08.962: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
        10-06 14:02:08.962: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setTranslationY (F)V
        10-06 14:02:09.072: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.onHoverEvent, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.dispatchHoverEvent
        10-06 14:02:09.072: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5024: Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView$HomeView;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
        10-06 14:02:09.072: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
        10-06 14:02:09.072: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0004 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView$HomeView;.dispatchHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
        10-06 14:02:09.102: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent
        10-06 14:02:09.102: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2938: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent;)V
        10-06 14:02:09.102: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
        10-06 14:02:09.302: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.getAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineHorizontalScrollView.getAlpha
        10-06 14:02:09.302: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2950: Landroid/widget/HorizontalScrollView;.getAlpha ()F
        10-06 14:02:09.302: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
        10-06 14:02:09.312: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineHorizontalScrollView;.getAlpha ()F
        10-06 14:02:09.312: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.setAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineHorizontalScrollView.setAlpha
        10-06 14:02:09.312: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2951: Landroid/widget/HorizontalScrollView;.setAlpha (F)V
        10-06 14:02:09.312: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
        10-06 14:02:09.322: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineHorizontalScrollView;.setAlpha (F)V
        10-06 14:02:09.512: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineLinearLayout.<init>
        10-06 14:02:09.512: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 2987: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;I)V
        10-06 14:02:09.512: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
        10-06 14:02:09.512: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x0003-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;I)V
        10-06 14:02:09.512: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.getAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineLinearLayout.getAlpha
        10-06 14:02:09.523: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2991: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.getAlpha ()F
        10-06 14:02:09.523: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
        10-06 14:02:09.532: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.getAlpha ()F
        10-06 14:02:09.532: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.getTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineLinearLayout.getTranslationX
        10-06 14:02:09.532: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2994: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.getTranslationX ()F
        10-06 14:02:09.532: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
        10-06 14:02:09.532: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.getTranslationX ()F
        10-06 14:02:09.532: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.setAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineLinearLayout.setAlpha
        10-06 14:02:09.532: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3001: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
        10-06 14:02:09.542: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
        10-06 14:02:09.542: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
        10-06 14:02:09.542: I/dalvikvm(414): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.setTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineLinearLayout.setTranslationX
        10-06 14:02:09.542: W/dalvikvm(414): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3007: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.setTranslationX (F)V
        10-06 14:02:09.542: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
        10-06 14:02:09.542: D/dalvikvm(414): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.setTranslationX (F)V
        10-06 14:02:29.956: I/IOException(414): IOException
        10-06 14:02:29.956: W/System.err(414): java.net.UnknownHostException: www.mille-et-une-tunisie.com
        10-06 14:02:29.981: W/System.err(414):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
        10-06 14:02:29.981: W/System.err(414):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
        10-06 14:02:29.981: W/System.err(414):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
        10-06 14:02:29.981: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
        10-06 14:02:29.991: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
        10-06 14:02:29.991: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
        10-06 14:02:29.991: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
        10-06 14:02:29.991: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
        10-06 14:02:29.991: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
        10-06 14:02:29.991: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1018)
        10-06 14:02:30.001: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:512)
        10-06 14:02:30.001: W/System.err(414):  at com.itgrapes.rss.ContainerData.getFeeds(ContainerData.java:50)
        10-06 14:02:30.011: W/System.err(414):  at com.itgrapes.fragment.FeedPlayerIndexFragment.<init>(FeedPlayerIndexFragment.java:24)
        10-06 14:02:30.011: W/System.err(414):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        10-06 14:02:30.011: W/System.err(414):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
        10-06 14:02:30.011: W/System.err(414):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:384)
        10-06 14:02:30.011: W/System.err(414):  at com.itgrapes.viewpager.FragmentsSliderActivity$TabsAdapter.getItem(FragmentsSliderActivity.java:103)
        10-06 14:02:30.011: W/System.err(414):  at com.itgrapes.viewpager.FragmentsSliderActivity$TabsAdapter.getItem(FragmentsSliderActivity.java:1)
        10-06 14:02:30.011: W/System.err(414):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:95)
        10-06 14:02:30.011: W/System.err(414):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:649)
        10-06 14:02:30.011: W/System.err(414):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:783)
        10-06 14:02:30.021: W/System.err(414):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1016)
        10-06 14:02:30.021: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        10-06 14:02:30.021: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        10-06 14:02:30.021: W/System.err(414):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        10-06 14:02:30.021: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        10-06 14:02:30.021: W/System.err(414):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
        10-06 14:02:30.021: W/System.err(414):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
        10-06 14:02:30.031: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        10-06 14:02:30.031: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        10-06 14:02:30.031: W/System.err(414):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        10-06 14:02:30.031: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        10-06 14:02:30.031: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        10-06 14:02:30.031: W/System.err(414):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        10-06 14:02:30.041: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        10-06 14:02:30.041: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
        10-06 14:02:30.041: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
        10-06 14:02:30.041: W/System.err(414):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        10-06 14:02:30.041: W/System.err(414):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        10-06 14:02:30.041: W/System.err(414):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        10-06 14:02:30.052: W/System.err(414):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        10-06 14:02:30.052: W/System.err(414):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        10-06 14:02:30.052: W/System.err(414):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        10-06 14:02:30.052: W/System.err(414):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        10-06 14:02:30.052: W/System.err(414):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        10-06 14:02:30.062: I/IOException(414): IOException
        10-06 14:02:30.062: W/System.err(414): java.net.UnknownHostException: www.mille-et-une-tunisie.com
        10-06 14:02:30.072: W/System.err(414):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:497)
        10-06 14:02:30.082: W/System.err(414):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
        10-06 14:02:30.082: W/System.err(414):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
        10-06 14:02:30.082: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
        10-06 14:02:30.082: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
        10-06 14:02:30.082: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
        10-06 14:02:30.082: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
        10-06 14:02:30.082: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
        10-06 14:02:30.092: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
        10-06 14:02:30.092: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1018)
        10-06 14:02:30.092: W/System.err(414):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:512)
        10-06 14:02:30.092: W/System.err(414):  at com.itgrapes.rss.ContainerData.getFeeds(ContainerData.java:50)
        10-06 14:02:30.092: W/System.err(414):  at com.itgrapes.fragment.FeedPlayerHebergementFragment.<init>(FeedPlayerHebergementFragment.java:24)
        10-06 14:02:30.102: W/System.err(414):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        10-06 14:02:30.102: W/System.err(414):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
        10-06 14:02:30.112: W/System.err(414):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:384)
        10-06 14:02:30.112: W/System.err(414):  at com.itgrapes.viewpager.FragmentsSliderActivity$TabsAdapter.getItem(FragmentsSliderActivity.java:103)
        10-06 14:02:30.112: W/System.err(414):  at com.itgrapes.viewpager.FragmentsSliderActivity$TabsAdapter.getItem(FragmentsSliderActivity.java:1)
        10-06 14:02:30.112: W/System.err(414):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:95)
        10-06 14:02:30.112: W/System.err(414):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:649)
        10-06 14:02:30.112: W/System.err(414):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:783)
        10-06 14:02:30.112: W/System.err(414):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1016)
        10-06 14:02:30.122: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        10-06 14:02:30.122: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        10-06 14:02:30.122: W/System.err(414):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        10-06 14:02:30.122: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        10-06 14:02:30.158: W/System.err(414):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
        10-06 14:02:30.162: W/System.err(414):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
        10-06 14:02:30.162: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        10-06 14:02:30.162: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        10-06 14:02:30.171: W/System.err(414):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        10-06 14:02:30.171: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        10-06 14:02:30.171: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        10-06 14:02:30.171: W/System.err(414):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        10-06 14:02:30.181: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        10-06 14:02:30.181: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
        10-06 14:02:30.181: W/System.err(414):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
        10-06 14:02:30.181: W/System.err(414):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        10-06 14:02:30.181: W/System.err(414):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        10-06 14:02:30.181: W/System.err(414):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        10-06 14:02:30.181: W/System.err(414):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        10-06 14:02:30.181: W/System.err(414):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        10-06 14:02:30.181: W/System.err(414):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        10-06 14:02:30.191: W/System.err(414):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        10-06 14:02:30.191: W/System.err(414):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        10-06 14:02:30.222: D/AndroidRuntime(414): Shutting down VM
        10-06 14:02:30.222: W/dalvikvm(414): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414): java.lang.NullPointerException
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at com.itgrapes.rss.ListFeedAdapter.getCount(ListFeedAdapter.java:36)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:454)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at com.itgrapes.fragment.FeedPlayerIndexFragment.onCreateView(FeedPlayerIndexFragment.java:32)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:139)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:804)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1016)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        10-06 14:02:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        10-06 14:02:32.692: I/Process(414): Sending signal. PID: 414 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding http in the url passed to getFeeds(String urlPage)? like:
urlPage = "http://"+urlPage;

Comment: This is how i call it
   String url="http://www.test.com/index.php?format=feed&amp;type=rss";
 ArrayList<Feed> feeds = ContainerData.getFeeds(url);